# Can not load html file in amp iframe

Tags: iframe, drupal, twig, drupal-8, amp-html

I want to create an html page and use it in the src attribute of the amp-iframe tag.
The amp-iframe tag then (as i understood from some examples) creates the iframe and loads the html page.
In drupal though, i can not find a way to use this html page in a twig template.
Is there a way to find a path inside drupal for this html page and use this path in the src?
I know drupal works with templates and twig files but in the amp examples everyone uses html.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Further, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Also learn how to post [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Problem could be that you're trying to add amp-iframe content that's on the same origin as your page domain. That's forbidden for security reasons (mostly to do with the way the same-origin policy uses synthetic origins inside iframes).

The fix is to make sure that external JS is served from a different origin to your AMP. So if your AMPs are on example.com then you should serve the iframed JS from SOMEOTHERORIGIN.example.com

Share your code for better under standing of your issue.

Also refer - https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-iframe-origin-policy.md

Comment: Thank you for the response. It was part of the problem actually. I had to remove the "allow-same-origin" from sandbox. That fixed the problem with that.